Connected and bounded space that is not totally bounded
I am considering metric spaces that are bounded but not totally bounded. Obviously, any finite space is trivially totally bounded, so we only need to consider infinite spaces. Common counterexamples include $[0, 1] \cap \mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and any infinite discrete space. These spaces are disconnected. I am wondering whether there is a connected and bounded space that is not totally bounded. I believe I have found a counterexample:
Consider $\mathbb{R}$ under the standard bounded metric $\bar{d}$; i.e., $\bar{d} (x, y) = \min\{ d (x, y), 1 \}$, where $d$ is the standard metric $d (x, y) = |y - x|$. That $\bar{d}$ is a metric and that $(\mathbb{R}, \bar{d})$ is bounded are trivial. That $\bar{d}$ generates the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is also easy to show: the basis elements of $(\mathbb{R}, d)$ and $(\mathbb{R}, \bar{d})$ coincide for $\varepsilon < 1$. Hence, since $(\mathbb{R}, d)$ is connected, then so is $(\mathbb{R}, \bar{d})$. But $(\mathbb{R}, \bar{d})$ is not totally bounded, since, for instance, there is no finite cover of the space by balls of the form $B_\bar{d} \left( x, \frac{1}{2} \right)$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}$.
Is my reasoning valid? If so, since such a "bounded" metric can be constructed for any metric, does this mean that (more generally) there is no topological property that can be added to boundedness to make a space totally bounded; i.e., like boundedness, total boundedness only depends on the metric?
EDIT: Clearly, compactness directly implies total boundedness. Are there topological properties other than compactness that, along with boundedness, are sufficient for a space to be totally bounded?

Your example is correct. I don't quite understand your final question. For instance, every compact metric space is totally bounded.

@PhoemueX Thank you. Right, I forgot that compactness automatically implies total boundedness! What about properties other than compactness? I am looking for properties that, together with boundedness, imply total boundedness.

Your reasoning is correct. There are no such properties that are useful.
What you have sketched is a proof (and a correct one, as far as I can tell) of the following statement:
Suppose $M$ is a metric space that is not totally bounded. Then $M$ is homeomorphic to a metric space that is bounded, but not totally bounded.
But this implies the following statement:
Suppose P is a topological property such that any bounded metric space with P is totally bounded. Then any metric space with P is totally bounded.
This is because, if P does not imply total boundedness on its own, it must be because there is some metric space $M$ that is not totally bounded and whose topology satisfies P. But then by the above statement, there is a metric space $M'$ with the same topology (satisfying P), which is bounded but not totally bounded, giving us a contradiction.
Thus, any topological property that implies total boundedness when combined with boundedness, also implies total boundedness on its own.

Great. Thank you for this answer!
